# Hibernate criteria query not respecting multiple restrictions

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I am trying to query 2 tables using criteria. Below is the method:

```
   public UserEntity getUserOverView(long userId, String receiptMonth) {

  Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
   UserEntity user = new UserEntity();

  try {
     session.beginTransaction();

          Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(UserEntity.class, "user")
           .createAlias("user.receiptEntitySet", "receipt")
           .add(Restrictions.eq("receipt.dateCreated", receiptMonth))
           .add(Restrictions.eq("user.userId", userId));


     user = (UserEntity) criteria.uniqueResult();

  } catch (Exception ex) {

     System.out.print(ex.getMessage());
  } finally {

     session.getTransaction().commit();
     session.close();

  }

  return user;
```

}

The above is successfully respecting the userId, however, I want to filter on the 'receiptMonth' in the other table. It seems to be ignoring the 'receiptMonth' restriction completely.

UserEntity:

```
    package za.co.skizzel.infrastructure.entities;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class UserEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Column(name="userId", unique = true, nullable = false, updatable = false )
  private Long userId;

  @Column(name="email")
  private String email;

  @Column(name="password")
  private String password;

  @Column(name="name")
  private String name;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "userEntity" , cascade = { CascadeType.ALL } )
  private Set<ReceiptEntity> receiptEntitySet;

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "userEntity" , cascade = { CascadeType.ALL } )
   private Set<CategoryEntity> categoryEntitySet;

   public Set<CategoryEntity> getCategoryEntitySet() {
      return categoryEntitySet;
   }

   public void setCategoryEntitySet(Set<CategoryEntity> categoryEntitySet) {
      this.categoryEntitySet = categoryEntitySet;
   }

   public Long getUserId() {
      return userId;
   }

   public void setUserId(Long userId) {
      this.userId = userId;
   }

   public String getEmail() {
      return email;
   }

   public void setEmail(String email) {
      this.email = email;
   }

   public String getPassword() {
      return password;
   }

   public void setPassword(String password) {
      this.password = password;
   }

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }

   public Set<ReceiptEntity> getReceiptEntitySet() {
      return receiptEntitySet;
   }

   public void setReceiptEntitySet(Set<ReceiptEntity> receiptEntitySet) {
      this.receiptEntitySet = receiptEntitySet;
   }

   public UserEntity(){};

   public UserEntity(long userId){
      this.userId = userId;
   };

}
```

ReceiptEntity:

```
    package za.co.skizzel.infrastructure.entities;


import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name="receipt")
public class ReceiptEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Column(name="ReceiptId", unique = true, nullable = false, updatable = false )
  private Long receiptId;

  @Column(name="alias")
  private String alias;

   @Column(name="categoryId")
   private long categoryId;

  @Column(name="DateCreated")
  private String dateCreated;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="userId", nullable=false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private UserEntity userEntity;

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "receiptEntity" , cascade = { CascadeType.ALL } )
   private Set<ImageEntity> imageEntitySet;

   private long userId;

   public long getUserId() {
      return userId;
   }

   public void setUserId(long userId) {
      this.userId = userId;
   }

   public long getCategoryId() {
      return categoryId;
   }

   public void setCategoryId(long categoryId) {
      this.categoryId = categoryId;
   }

   public Long getReceiptId() {
    return receiptId;
  }

  public void setReceiptId(Long receiptId) {
    this.receiptId = receiptId;
  }

  public String getAlias() {
    return alias;
  }

  public void setAlias(String alias) {
    this.alias = alias;
  }

  public String getDateCreated() {
    return dateCreated;
  }

  public void setDateCreated(String dateCreated) {
    this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
  }

  public UserEntity getUserEntity() {
    return userEntity;
  }

  public void setUserEntity(UserEntity userEntity) {
    this.userEntity = userEntity;
  }

   public ReceiptEntity() {};

}
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong? Any guidance would be appreciated?

Thanks
Luke

EDIT

I am expecting something like:

```
select * from user, receipt where user.userId = '8' and receipt.dateCreated = 'January 2014'
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
      Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(UserEntity.class)
       .createAlias("receiptEntitySet", "receipt")
       .add(Restrictions.eq("receipt.dateCreated", receiptMonth))
       .add(Restrictions.eq("userId", userId));
```

**EDIT**

This query will return `UserEntity` as a whole, that matches the criteria. For example, if you have one `userEntity` with two `ReceiptEntity`s in `receiptEntitySet` out of which one has `dateCreated = receiptMonth`, as a result you will get `userEntity` with both receipt entities in `receiptEntitySet`. That `userEntity` will be *attached* entity (bound to Hibernate session) and will represent the database state of that object, which includes both receipt entities.

Your options depend on your use case, but generally you could keep the user and receipts in separate fields, you could fill the receipts by looping through them

```
List<ReceiptEntity> filteredReceipts = new ArrayList<ReceiptEntity>();
for (ReceiptEntity receipt : user.getReceiptEntitySet()) {
    if (receipt.getDateCreated().equals(receiptMonth) {
        filteredReceipts.add(receipt);
    }
}
```

Or, create a query that will fetch them

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(ReceiptEntity.class)
       .createAlias("user", "user")
       .add(Restrictions.eq("dateCreated", receiptMonth))
       .add(Restrictions.eq("user.userId", userId));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What do you expect as a result? If you expect to get `UserEntity` with its `receiptEntitySet` filtered to just contain those with given `receiptMonth`, then your expectation is wrong. This query should return the `UserEntity` with given id, with all its fields, if it contains at least one `ReceiptEntity` with given `dateCreated`.

Comment: I am expecting my query to return only results based on a given userId and receiptMonth. View my edit.

Comment: Your query will return `UserEntity` as a whole, based on your criteria. If you have `userEntity` with `userId=1` and two `ReceiptEntity`s in `receiptEntitySet`, one of which has `creationDate = receiptMonth`, you will get the whole `userEntity` with both receipt entities. If you need just the one receipt entity which matches the `receiptMonth`, you will need another/different query.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: I've edited my answer, and added things mentioned in comments

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some fancy SQL here. SQL has no idea how to compare 'January 2014' to a date field. Further, you can't just compare the two dates, since a date at the beginning of the month does not equal a date at the end of the month (or day, or hour, or minute....etc), so you need to extract the month and the year from the target field to filter against, and compare each to the month and year you want to filter by.

Something along these lines might help you, I think:

```
    public void test(){
        SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM yyyy");
        Date d = null;
        String userId = "userId";
        try {
            d = f.parse("January 2014");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(d!= null){
            System.out.println("Date is: "+d.toString());
            Criteria c = this.getSession().createCriteria(UserEntity.class)
                .add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("extract('month' from cast('"+d.toString()+"' as timestamp)) = extract('month' from reciept.dateCreated) and extract('year' from cast('"+d.toString()+"' as timestamp)) = extract('year' from reciept.dateCreated)"))
                .add(Restrictions.eq("userId", userId));
         }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am not doing a date compare, simple just trying to query on all records that where created with that parameter (January 2014).